# WPF - Combobox SelectedItem not getting set?

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, selecteditem, itemssource

I have a ComboBox that has its ItemsSource bound to a static `List<CustomSettings>` of options. The ComboBox is part of a form which is bound to a CustomObject class, and one of the properties on that class is a CustomSettingProperty.

I would like to bind the SelectedItem of the ComboBox to the property specified in the CustomObject, however `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CustomSettingProperty}"` is not setting the default selected item. Using breakpoints I can see that it is calling the `get;` method, so I think the problem might be in the fact the CustomSettingProperty is created separately from the `List<CustomObject>` so WPF does not think it is the same item.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or perhaps an alternative since the CustomSettings class does contain an Id?

Comment: Can you give the code for CustomSettingProperty? And possibly an example of how you are setting it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If the item that is selected is not the same instance that is contained in the List, you must override Equals() in the CustomObject to let the ComboBox know that it is the same object.

If it's the same instance, maybe it's only a simple thing such as setting the BindingMode to TwoWay:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CustomSettingProperty,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think about overriding Equals... I won't be making that mistake again (I hope)

Comment: I have the same problem but I have been overridden `Equals()` How can I setting the BindingMode? Note: I am using c# and Winforms

Comment: Mode is TwoWay by default is it not?

Comment: From MSDN > A programmatic way to determine whether a dependency property binds one-way or two-way by default is to get the property metadata of the property using GetMetadata and then check the Boolean value of the BindsTwoWayByDefault property.

Comment: Thanks @Heinz K but how to override Equals()? Can you please give small example.

Comment: In my case just simply override Object.Equals throws StackOverflowException. I think the whole answer is to implement full IEquatable<T> that means implementing its Equals method and overriding Object.Equals(Object) and Object.GetHashCode methods as in [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx) (see the end of "Remarks" section - "Notes to Implementers" - and "Examples" section).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, It was The Prism's Event Aggregator was passed with reference type so That the ui thread stops processing