# Custom equality comparer for WPF ComboBox

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, combobox

When we bind the combobox's SelectedItem to a property, normally it will use the Equals method of the object type to determine the selected item that should be displayed in the ComboBox view. (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506193/wpf-combobox-selecteditem-not-getting-set), for example)

Is it possible to have my own comparer for this, without needing to modify the class' equals method? The reason I don't want to modify the method directly is because the class is also used for business logic and I don't want my equality comparer to affect other things that use the same class

Comment: can you create another class derived from the main class?

Comment: @DJ but I cannot control which implementation is passed to my viewmodel

Comment: What about to use `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedItem`. Then you can put your custom compare logic to find the index of the item in view model.

Comment: Why not use `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` instead of `SelectedItem`?

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I don't want to modify the method directly is because the class is also used for business logic and I don't want my equality comparer to affect other things that use the same class

This usually indicates a wrapper that is needed:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public override string ToString() { ... }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) { ... }

    public T UnderlyingRecord { get; set; }
}
```

This way you can carry on as normal and only the view will use the wrapper object.